# Manipulate colors through a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, colors, frontend

I am trying to create a for loop to manipulate the background of a page in Javascript,
I would like to create a fade in effect from rgb(0;0;0) to rgb(255;0;0)

But I got very stuck in the loop, I didn't find a way to pass a variable to the rgb() function.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var r;

function change() {
  var doc = document.body;
  var color;

  for(r = 0; r < 256; r++){
    color = rgb(r; 0; 0);
    doc.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

setInterval(change, 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var r = 0;

function change() {
    color = 'rgb(' + r +', 0, 0)';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    r < 256 ? r++ : 0;
}

setInterval(change, 100);
```

Comment: maybe you need to clear the interval when r == 256, check the value of r in console

Answer (score 2):

For setting color, you can use template literals, as backgroundColor property needs to be a string

```js
color = `rgb(${r}, 0, 0)`;
doc.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating a smooth **60fps** transition, it's better to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`.

By calling `setInterval(change, 100)`, the background color will only be updated once every 100ms. Most devices refresh their screens 60 times a second. So, in order to get a smooth transition, you need to update the background color once every **16.67ms** (1second/60). But, passing 16.67 to `setInterval` is not a reliable way to do this. This is where `requestAnimationFrame` comes in. When you put some code inside a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, the browser makes sure that that code gets executed just before the next repaint.

These are some great resources to learn more about this:

[Window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

[Rendering Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering)

[Optimize JavaScript Execution](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/optimize-javascript-execution)

[Jake Archibald: In The Loop - JSConf.Asia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)

This recursive `change` function takes a callback and the value of red and calls itself using `requestAnimationFrame` till the value of red reaches 255. If you have passed a callback, it gets fired after the transition.

```js
function change(callback, r) {
  r = r === undefined ? 0 : r;
  if (r >= 0 && r < 256) {
    const color = `rgb(${r}, 0, 0)`;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      change(callback, r + 1);
    });
  } else {
    callback && callback();
  }
}

change(() => {
  alert('Transition complete');
});
```

Also, if you're using `setInterval`, don't forget to clear it using `clearInterval` once the transition is complete.

[WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

[WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Answer (score 0):

This `fade` function uses an `async` loop to gradually change the `red` component of the background color from `0` to `255`:

```js
const fade = async () => {
  const getRed = () => +window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null)
    .backgroundColor
    .match(/\d+/)[0];
  while (getRed() < 255) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${getRed() + 1}, 0, 0)`;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
  }
}
fade();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```